# SQL Server Error : The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert values into a table in 1 SQL Server from another SQL Server using the following syntax:

```
SELECT * into [PWSQL0001-US].[test_database].[dbo].[wedata] FROM  [mon-qa-01].[wma].[ci].[wemqadata]
```

But I get the following error:

> The object name PWSQL0001-US.test_database.dbo.wedata contains more
>   than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Basically, I want to transfer every values from [mon-qa-01].[wma].[ci].[wemqadata] to [PWSQL0001-US].[test_database].[dbo].[wedata] using an sql query.

My last option could be to use SSIS, but I want to first try using a query and proceed with it, rather than using SSIS or Import/Export first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That does not sound like a SQL Server error, because SQL Server allows 4-part naming.

Comment: It's a limitation of the [`INTO ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql) style. Write an `INSERT ... SELECT` instead, or run your query on the `PWSQL0001-US` server so that you don't need to use a four-part name.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever . I tried it, seems there should be a linked Server connected to it. It gives me this error after trying INSERT ... Select :
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 11
Could not find server 'mon-qa-01' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix error comes from the INTO
[You can't INTO a linked server table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql)

> To create the table in another database on the same instance of SQL Server, specify new_table as a fully qualified name in the form database.schema.table_name.
>
> You cannot create new_table on a remote server; however, you can populate new_table from a remote data source.

Wrong:

```
*****[PWSQL0001-US]******.[test_database].[dbo].[wedata]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the select * into from to a insert into .... select * from.

```
select * into [server].[database].[schema].[table1] 
from [server].[database].[schema].[table2]
-- this is wrong
```

Do instead

```
insert into [server].[database].[schema].[table1]
select *
from [server].[database].[schema].[table2]
-- this is right
```